# How to resolve pdf parsing error

Tags: scala, pdf, pdf-parsing

scala code :

```
    val file = new File(path + name)
    val raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r")
    val channel = raf.getChannel()
    val buf = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size())
    val pdffile = new PDFFile(buf)           // line 5
```

here, file is referring to pdf file. path is the address of pdf file and name is name of file.

In normal case, it executes fine, but in some pdf files, it throws error in line 5 as :

```
com.sun.pdfview.PDFParseException: Expected 'xref' at start of table
    at com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile.readTrailer(PDFFile.java:974) ~[pdf-renderer-1.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile.parseFile(PDFFile.java:1175) ~[pdf-renderer-1.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile.<init>(PDFFile.java:126) ~[pdf-renderer-1.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile.<init>(PDFFile.java:102) ~[pdf-renderer-1.0.5.jar:na]
```

I think this pdf file has some problem with its format or content. When i made another pdf file using save as with this pdf file and used that new created pdf file, it worked fine.

So how can i resolve this problem so that whetehr i use proper file or bad file, my code should work fine.

**EDIT**

I found the following in the com/sun/pdfview/PDFFile.java description

```
@throws PDFParseException if the document appears to be malformed, or
       its features are unsupported
```

.

Comment: Can you provide a sample PDF causing that failure? I assume the pdf renderer expects PDFs with cross reference tables; but since PDF 1.5 an alternative way to add cross reference information became available, cross reference streams. I think your failing PDFs use these cross reference streams.

Comment: If my pdf is using cross reference stream, then how can i resolve this problem ?

Comment: Either change your work flow to only include PDFs with cross reference tables or use a different PDF rendering library which gets along with cross reference streams.